# Create variable with multiple return of numpy where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hi i am stata user and now iam trying to pass my codes in stata to python/pandas. In this case i want to create a new variables `size` that assign the value 1 if the number of jobs is between 1 and 9, the value 2 if jobs is between 10 and 49, 3 between 50 and 199 and 4 for bigger than 200 jobs.

And aftewards, if it is possible label them (1:'Micro', 2:'Small', 3:'Median', 4:'Big')

```
id  year  entry  cohort  jobs  
1  2009    0     NaN      3
1  2012    1     2012     3
1  2013    0     2012     4
1  2014    0     2012     11
2  2010    1     2010     11
2  2011    0     2010     12
2  2012    0     2010     13       
3  2007    0     NaN      38
3  2008    0     NaN      58       
3  2012    1     2012     58       
3  2013    0     2012     70
4  2007    0     NaN      231
4  2008    0     NaN      241
```

I tried using this code but couldnt succed

`df['size'] = np.where((1 <= df['jobs'] <= 9),'Micro',np.where((10 <= df['jobs'] <= 49),'Small'),np.where((50 <= df['jobs'] <= 200),'Median'),np.where((200 <= df['empleo']),'Big','NaN'))`

Comment: there is a beautiful function called pd.cut for binning i.e to do exactly what are want, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called binning use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) i.e

```
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['jobs'],bins=[1,10,50,201,np.inf],labels=['micro','small','medium','big'])
```

Output:

```
   id  year  entry  cohort  jobs     new
0    1  2009      0     NaN     3   micro
1    1  2012      1  2012.0     3   micro
2    1  2013      0  2012.0     4   micro
3    1  2014      0  2012.0    11   small
4    2  2010      1  2010.0    11   small
5    2  2011      0  2010.0    12   small
6    2  2012      0  2010.0    13   small
7    3  2007      0     NaN    38   small
8    3  2008      0     NaN    58  medium
9    3  2012      1  2012.0    58  medium
10   3  2013      0  2012.0    70  medium
11   4  2007      0     NaN   231     big
12   4  2008      0     NaN   241     big
```

For multiple conditions you have to go for [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) not `np.where`. Hope that helps.
​

> ```
> numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)
> ```
>
> Where condlist is the list of your condtions, and choicelist is the
>   list of choices if condition is met. default = 0, here you can put
>   that as np.nan

Using `np.select` for doing the same with the help of `.between` i.e

```
np.select([df['jobs'].between(1,10),
           df['jobs'].between(10,50),
           df['jobs'].between(50,200),
           df['jobs'].between(200,np.inf)],
           ['Micro','Small','Median','Big']
           ,'NaN')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i've been trying to figure out the np.select but i couldnt manage, can you help with that plz? i think i will use it a lot in the future

Comment: Its mid night 12 here. I shld sleep, can I update the answer morning?